# Debug-Release в javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, отладка

Делаю ajax-заспрос из js кода. Проблема в том, что приходится при дебаге подменять адрес, на который отправляю ajax request на localhost, а когда публикую проект на сервере - указывать ip сервера. Приходится вносить изменения в js коде каждый раз. Подскажите, как правильно организовать это дело, чтобы это делалось автоматически. В качестве IDE использую Visual Studio 2015.